# Ansible delegate_to wrong host?

Tags: ansible

I use ansible on the machine HostAnsible to configure firewalls named FW1,FW2, and so on.

I want to supervise those firewalls, so I have a task like this:

```yaml
- name: Configure supervision
  mymodule:
    ...
  delegate_to: "{{ supervision_host }}"
```

The variable supervision_host is set at the top level of the inventory to HostSupervision.
I check it with a debug :

```yaml
- debug:
    var: supervision_host
```

It is correct on all firewalls

The task shows this :

```
FW1 -> HostSupervision(HostAnsible): BlahBlah
```

And the SSH connection is made on the HostAnsible and not the HostSupervision.

What is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I had defined a variable `ansible_host: HostAnsible` in my inventory, this was messing up with the delegate.
Problem solved.